# CS0120 error while using global function in Winform (C#)

Tags: c#

In my winform application, I need to convert from timestamp value to DateTime object all over the project. So this is what I did:

```
public class UnixTool {
    public DateTime Unix2Time(Int64 timeStamp, TimeZoneInfo LocalTimeZone) {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(baseTime.AddSeconds(timeStamp), LocalTimeZone);
    }

    public Int64 Time2Unix(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo LocalTimeZone) {
        return (Int64)(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, LocalTimeZone).Subtract(baseTime).TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

And in other classes, I tried to use `Unix2Time` method like:

```
DateTime dt =  UnixTool.Unix2Time(localTimeStampValue, localTimeZone);
```

But it occurred the error:

**CS0120 : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'UnixTools.Unix2Time(long, TimeZoneInfo)'**

What should I do to solve this problem? What is causing error on my program?

Comment: declare your functions as static

Comment: You need to declare these methods `static`. `public static DateTime Unix2Time` and `public static Int64 Time2Unix`

Comment: Also consider using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a static class with static methods like this:

```
public static class UnixTool {
    public static DateTime Unix2Time(Int64 timeStamp, TimeZoneInfo LocalTimeZone) {
        return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(baseTime.AddSeconds(timeStamp), LocalTimeZone);
    }

    public static Int64 Time2Unix(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo LocalTimeZone) {
        return (Int64)(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, LocalTimeZone).Subtract(baseTime).TotalSeconds);
    }
}
```

The class does not must be static.

Comment: Thanks for the well-working answer, but VS says that the class NEEDS to be static

Comment: That is because of the baseTime property (I bet, the baseTime property is in the UnixTool class). If you set the baseTime property to static, than you could use this solution without make the class static.

Comment: Oh yes... I forgot to explain what `baseTime` was and it is the property of the class. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `Unix2Time` as `static`:

```
public static DateTime Unix2Time(Int64 timeStamp, TimeZoneInfo LocalTimeZone)
```

and `Time2Unix` as well if you want to have the same behavior.

By default, methods in C# require an instance of the surrounding class.